# Java URLConnection NTLM proxy authentication - linux

Tags: java, linux, proxy, ntlm

I'm trying to connect to an url by proxy with NTLM authentication.

```
    proxy = new Proxy( Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress( host, 80 ) );
    Authenticator.setDefault(new Authenticator() {
        @Override
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            logger.info("Getting password authentication...");
            return new PasswordAuthentication(
                    "DOMAIN\\user",
                    "password".toCharArray() ) ;
        }
    });
    connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection( proxy );
    String credentials = username + ":" + password;
    String basicAuth = "Basic " + Base64.encode( credentials.getBytes() );
    connection.setRequestProperty( "Authorization", basicAuth );
    connection.setRequestMethod( "GET" );

    //username/password above != user/pass below
    String proxyAuth = Base64.encode( ("user:pass").getBytes() );
    proxyAuth = "Basic " + proxyAuth;
    connection.setRequestProperty( "Proxy-Connection", "Keep-Alive" );
    connection.setRequestProperty( "Proxy-Authorization", proxyAuth );

    connection.connect();
```

Everyting works fine on Windows, but its because of:

[JDK-Based NTLM Authentication](http://www.theresearchkitchen.com/archives/24)

> When Sun released the 1.4.2 version of the JDK, they slipped in
>   support for native NTLM authentication on Windows.

But on configuration:

> Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.8
>
> java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.161-3.b14.el6_9.x86_64

or

> java-1.8.0_162 oracle

Im getting this error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.security.ntlm.Client.type3(Client.java:161)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.ntlm.NTLMAuthentication.buildType3Msg(NTLMAuthentication.java:250)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.ntlm.NTLMAuthentication.setHeaders(NTLMAuthentication.java:225)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.doTunneling(HttpURLConnection.java:2114)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:183)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:162)
```

Found this bug described: [JDK-8151788](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8151788) where clearly says:

> Resolved In Build: b128

Am I missing something very simple about that? Is there any way I can deal with that problem by HttpURLConnection or should I find something else? 
Any suggestions are appreciated!

**@Edit**

I added logging to `getPasswordAuthentication()` and it seems like its never inside.
It led me to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8669726/java-proxy-authentication) topic and actually NullPointerException is no longer there. 
Now I'm getting:

> java.io.IOException: Unable to tunnel through proxy. Proxy returns "HTTP/1.1 407 authenticationrequired"

Comment: Have you checked that ntlm authentication works on the local machine without java?

Comment: You mean if credentials are correct? Yes, Im using this proxy in some other apps

Comment: You can provide a tcpdump capture ?

Comment: Here you can find openjdk's implementation : http://river-tiger.com/ntlm/NTLM.zip . Unzip and run with the jar file from this archive.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have access to provide tcpdump and also can't download your zip (company firewall), but thanks a lot for your time ;)

Answer (score 1):

The build b128 is a Java 9 build, and unluckily it seems it was not ported on Java 8 (I can't find any NTLM bug in any of the Java 8 bug fixes list such as http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/2col/8u161-bugfixes-4021380.html )
Maybe could you try running your app with an old openjdk's ntlm implementation that is working well. I have one with me but I'm not sure how to send you this jar file.

Comment: I added again here [ntlm-openjdk.zip](https://www.river-tiger.com/blog-resources/ntlm-openjdk.zip) , [Base64.java](https://www.river-tiger.com/blog-resources/Base64.java) and this example [NTLM_ProxyClient.java](https://www.river-tiger.com/blog-resources/NTLM_ProxyClient.java). I won't give support, if you need information please check [davenport documentation](http://davenport.sourceforge.net/ntlm.html) first.

Answer (score -1):

I found little workaround for my problem.

```
StringBuilder commandBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    commandBuilder.append( "curl -s " )
            .append( "--proxy $PXHOST:$PXPORT " )
            .append( "--proxy-user $PXUSER:$PXPASS " )
            .append( "--user $SNUSER:$SNPASS " )
            .append( "--url \"" ).append( requestURL ).append( "\" " )
            .append( "--request GET " )
            .append( "--header \"Accept:application/json\" " )
            .append( "--header \"Content-Type:application/json\"" );
ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder( "/bin/bash", 
            "-c", commandBuilder.toString() );
```

I don't find this solution any good, but its enough for me at this moment.

Comment: It's awful. Did you try with "my" ntlm jar file ?

Comment: And where is above "String Builder" solution do you use NTLM ??